# Why Objective C language option is not found in Doxygen GUI?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, doxygen, doxygen-wizard, doxygen-addtogroup

I am trying to use Doxygen GUI for generating the documentations for my iPhone project. In that there is an option as "select programming language to optimize results for". In this option I can't find the Objective C option. When I run the oxygen, Its showing only empty HTML files.

Please clarify..! Below is the screen shot...

[image]

Comment: did you figure this out? It seams to automatically do OK with Objective-C but would be good to know if there is an option we need to set

Answer (score 0):

You can look inside your `Doxyfile` (text configuration file). When generated with comments, the part looks like:

```
# Set the OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C tag to YES if your project consists of C
# sources only. Doxygen will then generate output that is more tailored for C.
# For instance, some of the names that are used will be different. The list
# of all members will be omitted, etc.

OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C  = NO

# Set the OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_JAVA tag to YES if your project consists of Java
# sources only. Doxygen will then generate output that is more tailored for
# Java. For instance, namespaces will be presented as packages, qualified
# scopes will look different, etc.

OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_JAVA   = NO

# Set the OPTIMIZE_FOR_FORTRAN tag to YES if your project consists of Fortran
# sources only. Doxygen will then generate output that is more tailored for
# Fortran.

OPTIMIZE_FOR_FORTRAN   = NO

# Set the OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_VHDL tag to YES if your project consists of VHDL
# sources. Doxygen will then generate output that is tailored for
# VHDL.

OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_VHDL   = NO

# Doxygen selects the parser to use depending on the extension of the files it
# parses. With this tag you can assign which parser to use for a given
# extension. Doxygen has a built-in mapping, but you can override or extend it
# using this tag. The format is ext=language, where ext is a file extension,
# and language is one of the parsers supported by doxygen: IDL, Java,
# Javascript, CSharp, C, C++, D, PHP, Objective-C, Python, Fortran, VHDL, C,
# C++. For instance to make doxygen treat .inc files as Fortran files (default
# is PHP), and .f files as C (default is Fortran), use: inc=Fortran f=C. Note
# that for custom extensions you also need to set FILE_PATTERNS otherwise the
# files are not read by doxygen.

EXTENSION_MAPPING      =
```

Apparently, the Objective-C is the option. The wizard does not reflect it. However, it is easy to set it by hand.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. May I know the location of Doxyfile generated. I am new to this tool.

Comment: I personally do not use the GUI front end. Just typing `doxygen -g` generates the `Doxyfile`. It is usually generated in the directory from which you launch the `doxygen`. It may be the path that you can see in the GUI front end. However, it need not to be neccessarily named `Doxyfile`. I do not know what the GUI app does. If you find it and it does not contain the comments, you can call `doxygen -u` (for update) to get them for the existing `Doxyfile`.